# Database design for many payment types

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm new to database design. This database is for an upholstery cleaning store. I have some doubts related to model billing part. This store accepts payments using money, credit/debt card, bank transfer, invoices and PayPal. So many options.
I've accessed [databaseanswers](http://www.databaseanswers.com) and currently analyzing 3 models:

- [Generic Model](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/payments_generic_model/index.htm);
- [Future of Payments](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/future_of_payments/index.htm);
- [Invoices](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/invoices_and_payments/index.htm).

In generic model, it fits perfectly for card payment, but not with bank transfer and PayPal. I didn't understand why table Customer_Payment_Methods has one to many relationship to Payments instead of a Payment can have (one to many) many payment methods.
Future of payments pretty much the same as before adding payment channels.
Invoice model is just for... invoices.

I noticed that a customer has an account which can have many payments. But how can I solve for money and paypal parts? Separate tables?

Comment: You shouldn't need separate tables for payments. Not sure what a bank transfer is. But you just need to add new payment types to the acceptable field choices. Likely those are from a table and just need to add them in. Not sure about the Customer_Payment_Methods without seeing the tables and how they are arranged.

Comment: @DCook I provide links for consulting the tables.